# Why Firebase console displays different language every time I sign in?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I am working for a while with [Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com) and this problem keeps occurring. Every time I sign into console, it is displayed in different language(German, Russian, French...) and only sometimes in English(which I prefer.
Is it possible to set default language so it doesn't change every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Firebase supports only 28 languages as listed below:[image]

And your Google Account language is not one that is listed that's okay.
The only thing you need to do is change your Google Account language by following these steps:

- Open your [Google account](https://myaccount.google.com/)
- Click **Data & personalization**.
- Scroll down to the **General preferences for the web​ panel**.
- Click **Language**.
- Select **Edit**.
- Choose one of the languages from the dropdown box you find suitable from the languages above, and click **Select**.

Your Firebase console, or maybe any other Google related service should be in language you desire.